# How to remove or re-position add to cart message

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to re-position the Woocommerce message

> "X Product" HAS BEEN ADDED TO YOUR CART.

But with no success. I tried with the hooks like these

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'wc_print_notices', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'wc_print_notices', 10 );
```

The above did not work at all.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

**Edit**

I also tried to call the template tag directly in the `content-single-product.php` file somewhere at the bottom like this

```
<?php wc_print_notices(); ?>
```

Still no message shows at the desired place.

```
<div class="summary entry-summary">

<?php
/**
* woocommerce_single_product_summary hook.
*
* @hooked woocommerce_template_single_title - 5
* @hooked woocommerce_template_single_rating - 10
* @hooked woocommerce_template_single_price - 10
* @hooked woocommerce_template_single_excerpt - 20
* @hooked woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart - 30
* @hooked woocommerce_template_single_meta - 40
* @hooked woocommerce_template_single_sharing - 50
*/
do_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary' );
?>

</div><!-- .summary -->

<php wc_print_notices();?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove it you could just hide it with CSS:

```
.woocommerce-message, .woocommerce-info { display:none; }
```

Or to reposition:

```
//Remove Message:
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'woocommerce_show_messages' );

//Show message call this function where you want the message displayed
woocommerce_show_messages();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already tried that but it did not work, probably the hook is deprecated now  https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/function-woocommerce_show_messages.html

Answer (score 0):

```
    //Might be a very late but to people looking still you could try these.
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'woocommerce_output_all_notices', 10 );
    add_action('woocommerce_before_single_product','your_function_name');
    function your_function_name(){
     //your code here 
    
    }

    //Here is the template that returns the output notices 
    //if you want to include in the banner as well
<div class="woocommerce-notices-wrapper">
          <?php     wc_print_notices(); ?>
      </div>
```